# How can I use std.typecons.Typedef with functions?

Tags: alias, d, typedef, initializer

I have:

```
typedef void function(int) handler = &noOp;
```

As typedef is deprecated, I'm told to use either alias (which doesn't allow to set a default initializer) or std.typecons.Typedef (which does). However, the following doesn't work:

```
import std.typecons;
alias handler = Typedef!(void function(int), &noOp);
```

How can I set a function type's initializer without `typedef`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good example of a time to know the basics - I think understanding the ins and outs of `struct` is more helpful than `Typedef` since you can do so much more with it. Here's how you can do this:

```
void noOp(int) {} 
struct handler { 
    void function(int) fn = &noOp;  // here's the initializer
    alias fn this;  // this allows implicit conversion
} 
void main() { 
    handler h; 
    assert(h == &noOp); // it was initialized automatically!
    static void other(int) {} 
    h = &other; // and you can still reassign it
}
```

The `alias this` is perhaps controversial - it allows implicit conversion to and from the base type, like `alias`, but this is different than `typedef`. You could also customize this by doing individual constructors, `opAssign` overloads, etc., depending on the exact behavior you need. Ask me and I can clarify, but also you will want to play with it and see if you like how it works now.

Comment: I knew of alias this but never see when to use it, nice one thanks!